# Hosting a tornado/websocket application

Tags: python, hosting, websocket, tornado

I wrote an application which makes use of the websocket implementation of Tornado and I am trying to find a host for it. As far as I can tell by reading google search results, google appengine does not support websockets at the moment. I'm not sure about heroku since I couldnt find any information. So my question is, if anybody knows a hoster where I could host my application?

Answer (score 5):

The easiest thing might be to use a general IaaS (Infrastructure as a Service) cloud provider such as Amazon EC2 or Rackspace. Or even just use a regular hosted server like with Dreamhost. With those you get direct access to the OS and network configuration and you can do whatever you want. The downside is those will be more expensive and you for EC2 and Rackspace you will need to manage the host itself.

**Update**: you can now use Websockets on Heroku. Here is some information about using [Websockets with Python on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-websockets).

Comment: Does the downvoter care to elaborate so that I can fix the answer?

Comment: Hi, I'm the downvoter. The question was specifically about a python/tornado app (that he'd already written), and your answer was to write it in node.js. Although node.js is great (I use it all the time) I think it's extremely unhelpful to suggest completely different technologies as an answer to a specific question.

Comment: @NickJennings, I've restructured the answer to capture my original intention better. I still provide the alternate suggest but it's clearly secondary now.

Comment: Hi kanaka, thanks for updating your post. However, it should be noted that Joyent servers can run non-node.js apps just as well. Although they specialize in node.js you can run tornado apps, or traditional php sites, on their servers without issue.

Comment: @NickJennings, yes, that's true. I mentioned them because they provide a lot of support and documentation for running node.js. Which makes sense given they were (are) the main driving force behind Node.js.