# Host a Python based Websocket server

Tags: python, websocket, hosting

I am looking to host a basic Websocket server.

The code I want to see running is : [FastFlicker](https://github.com/Paraintom/FastFlicker)

Do you know how  and where I can host this application online?

Comment: WebSocket Demo using Google App Engine Managed VMs and a Python runtime with the Tornado framework [gae-websockets-python-demo](https://github.com/artooro/gae-websockets-python-demo)

Comment: Perhaps this answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/9501039/2315612 applies (disclaimer: never tried this myself); it mentions Heroku next to Amazon EC and Rackspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is **OpenShift**, even with the free plan you can host **FastFlicker**.
Click **Add Application**, choose the good cartridges (Python 2.7).

Then use your gitHub repo url to get the source.

Once the application is running, you need to SSH it to change the address and the port (see [this Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34415774/openshift-tornado-websocketdemo-not-responding)).
To be able to ssh you need first to [generate a ssh key](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/OpenShift_Online/2.0/html/User_Guide/Generating_Keys_Manually4.html) and to add it in setting on the website

Ok, now [kill all processes that uses your port.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29217502/socket-error-address-already-in-use) (`lsof -i :8080`)

Start your application and now it's working!
(It is in `app-deployments/current/repo/` for me, then `python FastFlicker.py &`)

It is currently hosted here : ws://main-fastflicker.rhcloud.com:8000/
And to test it, you know [you can use this generic client.](http://cdn.rawgit.com/Paraintom/FastFlicker/897af0cc305975a59b836d008d378ef8c7c6c915/websocket.html?url=ws%3A%2F%2Fmain-fastflicker.rhcloud.com%3A8000%2F).

Answer (score 5):

PythonAnywhere dev here. Unfortunate we can't host websocket-based apps on our site right now.  The toggle you spotted enables/disables websockets for our in-browser consoles, it's not related to running your own websocket server.

I've added an upvote for websockets to our own issue tracker, but for now you'll have to use a different service :-(